# Search and replace a string within a string, but only if it's not within quotes

Tags: php, sql, regex, string

The string looks like this:

```
abc def
  123 'abc' abc "def"
  bla bla
```

So I want to replace `abc` with something else, but to not affect the abc that's within quotes. Same with `def`, which is using double quotes...

This is actually for a string that contains SQL queries, I want to replace table names without replacing by mistake data from fields which could contain the same word.

Comment: Will there be really only `'abc'` or could it also be `'Foo abc Bar'`?

Comment: What about escaped quotes? \" \' ?

Comment: what about `"abc'` (double and single quote) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expressions with negative lookahead and negative lookbehind. You can read more about that here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Here is an example that matches abc:

`(?<!['"])(?<target>abc)(?!['"])` - this will match any **abc** not surrounded by single or double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

A negative lookbehind and lookahead should suffice:

```
(?<!')abc(?!')
```

There's the negative lookbehind to ensure abc is not preceded by a single quote `(?<!')` as well as a negative lookahead to ensure that abc is is not followed by a single quote `(?!')`.

Obviously, this is trivially changeable to switch out single for double quotes:

```
(?<!")def(?!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Table names appear after specific keywords:

```
FROM tablename
JOIN tablename
INNER JOIN tablename
LEFT JOIN tablename
...
```

I would build a replacement pattern based on this fact.

Comment: Except where you *may or may not* have database and/or schema names specified.  Or table names enclosed in backquotes, or square braces.  Or their presence in SELECT statements, within function calls, CASE WHEN THEN logic, ON join predicates, WHERE clauses or a plethora of other logical arithmetic.  Or so many other places.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `regexp` like this one:

//
  $new_string = preg_replace("/\"(.*)\"|\'(.*)\'/","test",$string);

Answer (score 1):

Which version of sql are you using?  Some versions of sql (most?) don't have regular expression support.

The main approach that I'm aware of (in for example, MS SQL Server) is to write a function that actually parses the entire string, checking the conditions you are interested and replacing as and when necessary.

As this would be a multi-statement function, it has it's own overheads.  As this sounds like a one-off, that shouldn't be too bad, normally.

An alternative approach, which is best avoided in lower level languages, but possibly suitable in higher level languages...

Find all occurances that you DON'T want to replace, and replace them with a holding pattern.  (This pattern must be known to not already exist in the data.)  Do your replacement, then return the holding pattern to the original string.

```
Start = abc "abc" 'abc'
Step1 = abc "xxx" 'abc'    -- REPLACE('"abc", '"xxx"', start)
Step2 = abc "xxx" 'xxx'    -- REPLACE('''abc''', '''xxx''', step1)
Step3 = ??? "xxx" 'xxx'    -- REPLACE('abc', '???', step2)
Final = ??? "abc" 'abc'    -- REPLACE('xxx', 'abc', step3)
```

Comment: actually I need to do this in PHP, not sql :)

Comment: In which case, you don't need the SQL tag in your question :)